# Optional microseconds in Python Eve DATE_FORMAT setting

Tags: python, eve

Within my eve_settings (Python Eve) I have this line for global date format.

`'DATE_FORMAT': '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'`

However, I would like flexibility to be able to permit microseconds without needing to introduce a custom data type. The following would permit microseconds, but then does not appear to permit timestamps without the microseconds.

`'DATE_FORMAT': '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'`

I did try using `'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S(.%f)Z'` and `'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S[.%f]Z'` but they do not appear to be accepted.

Is it possible to have both formats within the DATE_FORMAT setting?